# Regex that matches any HTML tag with the content inside

Tags: html, regex

I'd like to use Regex to match HTML tag "head" and text inside them so I can delete them easily. I'm using a find and replace tool that is utilizing regex syntax and it really works great in replacing multiple files at once.

I tried doing a lot of syntax but I always fail.

http://regex101.com/r/aZ6pN5/2

Anyone can help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `.*` in your regex with `[\S\s]*?`, so that it would match line breaks also. You can't use `s` DOTALL modifier in JavaScript.

```
<head.*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/head>
```

`[\s\S]*?` This would do an non-greedy match of zero or more space or non-space characters.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aZ6pN5/3)

**OR**

To replace the contents of head tag.

```
(<head\b[^<>]*>)[\s\S]*?(<\/head>)
```

*Replacement string:*

```
$1stringyouwant$2
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aZ6pN5/4)

Comment: if your tool support dotall mode then you could use this `(?s)<head.*?>(.*?)<\/head>` regex.